# How do I edit a compact JS in order to add another line of code to it?

Tags: javascript

Somebody sent me a JS code which I simply used as it was.

I added it to my chromium based browser by using .AddJS(somecode).
It worked fine all the time, but then whatsapp changed something.

Now the code now throws an error saying:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , n.isMDBackend) is not a function https://web.whatsapp.com/2
Module isMDBackend was not found with e=>e.isMDBackend 2
n.isMDBackend) is not a function https://web.whatsapp.com/2
```

Googeling this error took me to [this github](https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js/issues/1758) trouble solving.

Somebody wrote this:

```
Quick fix:

edit Injected.js file...

comment the line:
window.Store.Wap = window.mR.findModule('queryLinkPreview')[0].default;

Set the window.Store.MDBackend to true

window.Store.MDBackend = true;
```

In my JS code, there is no "window.Store" string to be found, and no string regarding "MDBackend", so I simply added the following line

```
me.webkitx1.AddJS("window.Store.MDBackend = true;")
```

This however did not solve the problem.

In my code, I did find "queryLinkPreview" (which they mentioned).

In my JS code, I looks like this:

```
(...)ource(t);return r.includes(".queryLinkPreview")&&r.includes(".getProductOrCatalogLinkPreview")}))},8967(...)
```

It is so compacted that I wouldn't know how to add / edit it.

To make it readable again, I have tried JS Formatter, but it couldn't handle it.

I would therefore first like to ask what this kind of compacting is called. If I know the term, I guess I can find a way to revert it myself.

Thank you.

Part of the code:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=t():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],t):"object"==typeof exports?exports.WPP=t():e.WPP=t()}(self,(()=>(()=>{var __webpack_modules__={9742:(e,t)=>{"use strict";t.byteLength=function(e){var t=u(e),r=t[0],n=t[1]**strong text**
```

Comment: Why does your GitHub link go to freelancer?

Comment: It's called "minified"

Comment: @James Sorry, copy / paste must have not worked.